# VBA Check String array at index is nothing

Tags: arrays, vba

I am wondering how to check if a string array at a certain index has not been initialized.

I am using the Split function to determine the file extension of a file path, but in some cases the extension will not be included. My delimiter is ".", so only in the case that the extension is provided will there be a value at array index 1.

I have tried comparing my array at index 1 using Is Nothing, "", IsEmpty, and vbNullString without any success.

I also tried explicitly declaring the size of the array but then I get issues with assigning it to the value of the Split function.

A snippet of my code is as follows:

```
Dim filePath As String
Dim stringArr() As String

filePath = "C:\Users\Sarchwalk\Documents\fileName"
stringArr() = Split(filePath, ".") 'Problem here if stringArr size has been declared

If stringArr(1) = "" Then 'Error arises here
    MsgBox "String array at index 1 is empty"
End If
```

Comment: Try "If UBound(stringArr) = 0 Then" instead of "If stringArr(1) = """

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ubound,

```
If Ubound(stringArr) = Lbound(stringArr) Then 
    MsgBox "String array at index 1 is empty"
ElseIf stringArr(1) = "" Then 'Error arises here
    MsgBox "String array at index 1 is empty"
End If
```

If there is only one then Ubound will equal Lbound.  if not then we check for an empty string also.

Comment: Works great! Thanks :)